# Show alert after action in mvc3/4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, alert

I need to inform user about success/failure of clicked operation. In view I've prepared action link that goes to controller, performs database operation and returns with result. Then I'd like to show alert with message "done" or "failure". Everything should be done without reloading page. I've tried to define @Ajax.ActionLink and text/javascript function but it doesn't work at all... Please help. Thanks in advance.

Robert

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should include scripts: jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax like:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Inside View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myCallback(data) {
        if(!data.Success)
        {
             alert(data.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("id: " + data.Id);
        }
    }
</script>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Actionlink", // <-- Text to display
                 "GetDeneme", // <-- Action Method Name
                 new { id = "2"},
                 new AjaxOptions
                 {                         
                     HttpMethod = "POST", // <-- HTTP method
                     OnSuccess = "myCallback"
                 })
```

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetDeneme(string id)
        {
            var error = (id == "3");

            if (error)
            {
                return Json(new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "Error!" });
            }

            return Json(new { Success = true, Id = id });
        }
```